# XSLT trim length of text and show ellipsis

Tags: xslt

i have an RSS feed (link below) and I want to limit the length of text returned in the title node

RSS Feed:
https://news.google.co.uk/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=uk&hl=en&q=uk&output=rss

So I have added a parameter for the limit and set it to 20

I have then added a couple of test statements to check if the title node length is greater/less than 20.

The problem I have is that the less than test always outputs - even when a title is greater than 20!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="allowable-length" select="20"/>
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[position() &lt;= 6]">
        <xsl:sort select="pubDate" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(rss/channel/item/title) &lt;= $allowable-length">
          <li class="news">
            <a href="{link}" title="{title}">
              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </a>
          </li>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(rss/channel/item/title) &gt; $allowable-length">
          <li class="news">
            <a href="{link}" title="{title}">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(title, 1, 20)"/>
...            </a>
          </li>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Instead of <xsl:if> why not use <xsl:choose>??
It works like if,else-if, else

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work either, the otherwise block never fired.  There must be a problem with the test, what you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason this isn't working is that XPaths inside the `for-each` will be relative to `item`, but you are starting your paths back at `rss`.

You can also clean up this XSLT considerably by eliminating duplication. Give this a try.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:param name="allowable-length" select="20"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rss/channel/item[position() &lt;= 6]">
        <xsl:sort select="pubDate" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li class="news">
      <a href="{link}" title="{title}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(title, 1, $allowable-length)"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(title) &gt; $allowable-length">
           <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In cases such as these I make sure I test the right thing with some simple debugging. I inserted `[<xsl:value-of select="string-length(title)"/>]` and it showed `[0]` for everything, which is clearly not correct. Then I immediately saw the problem.

Comment: @Jongware I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. Are you saying there was a problem with the stylesheet above? Was it because of the missing `xsl` namespace?

Comment: @JLRishe thanks for the explinations, i was indeed trying to start back at the root RSS path rather than the relative path.  Thanks for also posting the refactored code - i'm fairly new to this so always good to see a better way of doing something!

Comment: @JL: sorry; I meant I used that line to debug the *original* XSLT. *There* it showed the "clearly wrong" value.

Answer (score 2):

The `xsl:for-each` statement

```
<xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[position()&lt;=6]">
```

will change the context node to the respective `item` element. So inside the `for-each` statement, you should use

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(title) &lt;= 20">
```

The expression `rss/channel/item` yields an empty node set because `item` doesn't have any `rss` children.

Comment: thank you this works perfect, node path was the issue after all :)